# Сделать волну из String в Java

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка "hello" или любая другая состоящая из 1 слова и маленьких букв, нужно на выходе в консоле получить:

Hello
hEllo
heLlo
helLo
hellO

Что б первую букву сделать большой, я кое как сообразил. А вот дальше весь мозг сломал. Понимаю что еще один цикл for нужен, который будет выводить строки ... Но чего-то не хватает.

```
String s = "hello";
        char [] myArray = s.toCharArray();
        int position = 0;
        System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(myArray[position]));
        for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(myArray[i]);
        }
```

Помогите кодом или направлением, куда копать.

Answer (score 3):

Например вы можете в цикле брать букву, переводить ее в верхний регистр, печатать содержимое массива, и после переводить букву в нижний регистр.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(myArray[i]);
            System.out.print(myArray);
            System.out.print(" ");
            myArray[i] = Character.toLowerCase(myArray[i]);
        }
```